# How to find row indexes of elements which have same value in a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, row

I have two 4x1 matrixes. They have the same elements but the row indexes of elements in the matrixes are different.

```
a = [200;100;100;300]
b = [100;100;200;300]
```

I need to find index numbers of matrix b's elements in matrix a.
For example, the third element of matrix b is 200 and the index number of 200 in matrix a is 1.

The result should be = `[2 3 1 4]`

I wrote this code but it didn't work because there are two 100s:

```
for i=1:4
    c(1,i) = find(a(:,1) == b(i,1));
end
```

I have this warning: `Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side.`

What should I do to have `[2 3 1 4]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [sort](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) `a` and `b` and use indexes of the sorted arrays to get the desired result:

```
[~,s1] = sort(a);
[~,s2] = sort(b);
c(s2) = s1;
```